# How do you make datetime list from dataframe row value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner in Python and I want to make a datetime list from existing values in my dataframe.

|  | booking_date | booking_check_in | days_of_stay | booking_currency | booking_earned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-09-14 | 2019-12-20 | 2 | 1 | 611632.0 |
| 1 | 2019-10-21 | 2019-11-01 | 1 | 1 | 742806.0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-02 | 2 | 1 | 1400000.0 |

I want to make a list of the date people stayed from booking_check_in by using `pd.date_range` as the start and days_of_stay for the periods, and make a new column of date_stayed from it.

date_stayed will replace booking_check_in and days_of_stay, and the booking_earned will be divided by the value of days_of_stays

It should be something like this as the result:

|  | booking_date | date_stayed | booking_currency | booking_earned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-09-14 | 2019-12-20 | 1 | 305816.0 |
| 1 | 2019-09-14 | 2019-12-21 | 1 | 305816.0 |
| 2 | 2019-10-21 | 2019-11-01 | 1 | 742806.0 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-02 | 1 | 700000.0 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-03 | 1 | 700000.0 |

I would truly appreciate it if someone could explain thoroughly and give me some ideas to achieve the result I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.index.repeat` with `pop`:

```
s = df.pop("days_of_stay")
df["booking_earned"] /= s
new_df = df.iloc[df.index.repeat(s)]
print(new_df.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
  booking_date booking_check_in  booking_currency  booking_earned
0   2019-09-14       2019-12-20                 1        305816.0
1   2019-09-14       2019-12-20                 1        305816.0
2   2019-10-21       2019-11-01                 1        742806.0
3   2020-01-01       2020-03-02                 1        700000.0
4   2020-01-01       2020-03-02                 1        700000.0
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution from another perspective! This is simpler and cleaner than the `pd.date_range` I'm fixated on, and it teaches me to utilize assign method better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Try:

```
# Convert To DateTime if Not Already
df['booking_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['booking_date'])
df['booking_check_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df['booking_check_in'])

# Distribute booking earned over number of days
df['booking_earned'] = df['booking_earned'] / df['days_of_stay']
# Create Date Ranges
df['booking_check_in'] = [pd.date_range(start=s, periods=p, freq='D')
                          for s, p in
                          zip(df['booking_check_in'], df['days_of_stay'])]
# explode into Rows drop extra columns and rename
df = (
    df.explode('booking_check_in', ignore_index=True)
        .drop(['days_of_stay'], axis=1)
        .rename(columns={'booking_check_in': 'date_stayed'})
)
```

`df`:

```
  booking_date date_stayed  booking_currency  booking_earned
0   2019-09-14  2019-12-20                 1        305816.0
1   2019-09-14  2019-12-21                 1        305816.0
2   2019-10-21  2019-11-01                 1        742806.0
3   2020-01-01  2020-03-02                 1        700000.0
4   2020-01-01  2020-03-03                 1        700000.0
```

---

How does this work?

1. Conversion [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['booking_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['booking_date'])
df['booking_check_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df['booking_check_in'])
```

When working with dates it's always useful to have them in the correct data type.

2. Normalizing daily earnings is simple division.

```
df['booking_earned'] = df['booking_earned'] / df['days_of_stay']

  booking_date booking_check_in  days_of_stay  booking_currency  booking_earned
0   2019-09-14       2019-12-20             2                 1        305816.0
1   2019-10-21       2019-11-01             1                 1        742806.0
2   2020-01-01       2020-03-02             2                 1        700000.0
```

Doing it at this step means less values to compute (as opposed to doing it after scaling up the DataFrame)

3. Creating the Date Ranges. For each row in the DataFrame we create a series of dates starting at `booking_check_in` and extending for `days_of_stay` periods via [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

```
df['booking_check_in'] = [pd.date_range(start=s, periods=p, freq='D')
                          for s, p in
                          zip(df['booking_check_in'], df['days_of_stay'])]
```

This can also be done with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on axis=1

```
# Distribute booking earned over number of days
df['booking_earned'] = df['booking_earned'] / df['days_of_stay']
# Create Date Ranges
df['booking_check_in'] = (
    df[['booking_check_in', 'days_of_stay']]
        .apply(lambda s: pd.date_range(start=s['booking_check_in'],
                                       periods=s['days_of_stay'],
                                       freq='D'),
               axis=1)
)
```

```
  booking_date                                                               booking_check_in
0   2019-09-14  DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-20', '2019-12-21'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
1   2019-10-21                DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
2   2020-01-01  DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-02', '2020-03-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

4. [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) into multiple rows:

```
df.explode('booking_check_in', ignore_index=True)
```

```
  booking_date booking_check_in  days_of_stay  booking_currency  booking_earned
0   2019-09-14       2019-12-20             2                 1        305816.0
1   2019-09-14       2019-12-21             2                 1        305816.0
2   2019-10-21       2019-11-01             1                 1        742806.0
3   2020-01-01       2020-03-02             2                 1        700000.0
4   2020-01-01       2020-03-03             2                 1        700000.0
```

5. Lastly clean up columns index etc with [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the `days_of_stay` column.

```
df = (
    df.explode('booking_check_in', ignore_index=True)
        .drop(['days_of_stay'], axis=1)
        .rename(columns={'booking_check_in': 'date_stayed'})
)
```

```
  booking_date date_stayed  booking_currency  booking_earned
0   2019-09-14  2019-12-20                 1        305816.0
1   2019-09-14  2019-12-21                 1        305816.0
2   2019-10-21  2019-11-01                 1        742806.0
3   2020-01-01  2020-03-02                 1        700000.0
4   2020-01-01  2020-03-03                 1        700000.0
```

Comment: This answer is very comprehensive and gets all the detail well explained. Thank you.